# Javascript: How to create a smooth rotation animation for an image? [Compass needle]

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I like to build a compass app for mobile devices. I've already created the function that returns the change-values for the compass-needle rotation. 
(e.g. 20) But if I just set the 'image-transform' to 'rotate(x deg)' it looks a bit jumpy, so my idea was to add a smooth animation for the  needle to move.

---

How to code a js-function that can add a animation for my compass needle?

IMPORTANT: What happens when the function is called with parameter '20', and 0.5 second (when the turn-20-onesecond animation isn't over yet) again called with a different parameter '-30'. SO one feature of the function must be to cancel the running animation and adds to the old change-value('20') the new change-value('-30') and starts another animation.

---

Hope you could understand my problem. Here my basic function:

```
var change_value=20;
function start_animation(change_value){ 
  $needle_element.css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(" + change_value + "deg)")
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you are working with or we really can't help you.

Comment: Just use a CSS transition instead.

Comment: I can not use CSS transition @ibrahimmahrir. I need to calculate the rotation value for the animation. That's not possible in css...

Comment: @jonas00 Why???

Comment: My code will not help you out @ScottMarcus. I've added my basic function but, I have to admit, that this is all I've got yet.

Comment: But transitions will do... well the transition between two states. So set by js, let CSS do the animation.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Show me some code that calculates the rotation value and I will believe you :)

Comment: @jonas00 I'll post a code snippett

Comment: Naah search MDN css transition. Not that hard.

Comment: @jonas00 Check the snippett that I've posted in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
// Get references to DOM elements
var input = document.getElementById("angle");
var btn = document.getElementById("btnGo");
var needle = document.getElementById("needle");

// Set up click event handler
btn.addEventListener("click", start_animation);

// Storage for the previous angle
var lastAngle = "";

function start_animation(){ 
  // Update the total angle needed
  lastAngle = +lastAngle + +input.value;
  
  // For testing:
  console.clear()
  console.log("Current total angle: " + lastAngle);

  // Move the needle:
  needle.style.transform = "rotate(" + lastAngle + "deg)";
}
```

```css
#needle {
  height:5px;
  background-color:#808080;
  width:100px;
  margin-top:100px;

  /* Initial value for rotate is needed for transition to work */
  transform:rotate(0);  

  /* CSS transition creates smooth effect */
  transition:all 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="angle" value="20"><button type="button" id="btnGo">Go!</button>
<div id="needle"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The trick is this style:  "transition:all 1.5s;" After this "transform:rotate"  will smoothly rotate image. Rotation speed can be set in transition style.